# How to get a black statusbar on iPhone X on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

By default the statusbar on an iPhone X looks like this:

[image]

But I would like to achieve this:

[image]

I tried setting the `preferredStatusBarStyle` to `lightContent` but it only worked after setting the background behind the statusbar to black.

To fix the rounded corners I ended up adding another subview with rounded corners.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .black

        let roundedView = UIView(
            frame: CGRect(
                x: 0,
                y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height,
                width: view.frame.width,
                height: view.frame.height
            )
        )
        roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        roundedView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        roundedView.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(roundedView)

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 60))
        label.text = "Black statusbar!"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        roundedView.addSubview(label)
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this is the best approach.. there must be a better way to achieve this.

---

**UPDATE**

This is a terrible idea because:

- As [@Moritz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227743/moritz) points out, the [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/) explicitly forbids this:

> **Don't mask or call special attention to key display features.** Don't attempt to hide the device's rounded corners, sensor housing, or
>   indicator for accessing the Home screen by placing black bars at the
>   top and bottom of the screen. Don't use visual adornments like
>   brackets, bezels, shapes, or instructional text to call special
>   attention to these areas either.

- The rounded corners at the top of the view might look nice, but you will have to add exceptions in the code to make sure the rounded corners are not shown on other iPhones. You will need to put this in all your ViewControllers / Storyboards.. That is not so great.
- The rounded corners at the bottom of the view will appear straight in screenshots, but the corners at the top (set manually) won't. This will be ugly when users share your app.

Comment: Safe area is causing a whole lot of trouble already with backwards compatibility, this is just going to be fuel in the fire.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Safe Area Layout is a solution to your problem.

I tried following the solution in my existing projects and it works fine.

- Set black background color (or what ever you want) to main view of your view controller.
- Now add child view (with white background) and set its constraints relative to Safe Area Layout (or follow Top and bottom layout guide if Xcode version is below 9).
- Consider this child view (with white background) as a main view and process further design with it.

Here is sample snapshot with result, By enabling or disabling Safe Area layout, I tested and implemented.

FYI: In these snapshots, main view has red background and child view has blue background color.

**Safe Area Layout:**
[image]

**AutoLayout**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question, maybe this is not such a good idea after all. But to continue the exercise: this is slightly better then doing it with code, but you will still have to repeat this for every view controller.. not ideal right?

Comment: I created an IBDesignable Custom View Interface Class and used the same.. You and your approach are absolutely right, that this may need manual practice for each view controller. But this won't be very hard to do it manually. And also, this idea can have control over the your interface areas beyond Apples restrictions within its guidelines. At this stage, until we find permanent solution, this may be good one. Have a nice day :)